# Openshift nodes storage configuration

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm looking for some info about what requirements are best practices for openshift storage in nodes which will execute dockers but I didn't find any clear solution.

My questions would be:

-is any shared storage mandatory for all nodes?

-can I control the directory where images will be placed?

-must be nfs directories that will be acceded by containers be already mounted in the node server?

Comment: Its unclear what you  are trying to ask with 2 of your 3 questions: 
"can I control the directory where images will be placed?"
What Images? Images that you build and push to a registry? Images that you pull to run on the platform?
"must be nfs directories that will be acceded by containers be already mounted in the node server?"
Are you trying  to ask if the nfs (storage) needs to be mounted on the node for the pods to be able to use it. The answer here is Yes. In order for a PVC to claim a PV the PV has to be created (and for that to happen it has to be mounted to the node.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for information about this and these are my conclusions:

If you need persistant storage for example db, jenkins master or any kind of storage you want to maintain every time a docker boots then you have to mount the storage in the nodes that can run docker that requires that persistent storage.

1. Mount in nodes any of these:
   NFS ,HostPath (single node testing only of course already mounted),GlusterFS,Ceph,OpenStack Cinder, AWS Elastic Block Store (EBS),GCE Persistent Disk ,iSCSI, Fibre Channel
2. Create persistent volumes in Openshift

Openshift nfs example creating file.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
  storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
 nfs:
   path: /tmp
   server: 172.17.0.2
```

Create from the file created

```
oc create -f file.yaml
```

3. Create a claim from the datastore, claims will search for persistent volumes available with the capacity required.

Then a claim will be used by pods.

For example let's claim 1GB ,later we will associate a claim with a pod.

Create nfs-claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-claim1
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce 
resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Create from the file created

```
oc create -f nfs-claim.yaml
```

4. Create a pod fo with the storage volume and with a claim.

-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: nginx-nfs-pod 
   labels:
     name: nginx-nfs-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-nfs-pod
      image: fedora/nginx 
      ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfsvol 
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html 
  volumes:
    - name: nfsvol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nfs-claim1
```

Some extra options like selinux settings must be required, but they are so well explained here (https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

- is any shared storage mandatory for all nodes?

No shared storage is *not* mandatory, but it is **highly** recommended (as most application will require some "state-full" storage,  which can only *really* be obtained with a shared storage provider. The following https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/index.html are options for such storage providers.